# Where to find legacy mbedtls documentation?

Tags: mbedtls

I am looking for the legacy mbedtls documentation.
It was available at tls.mbed.org before joining the trustedFirmware project. Now, sadly, it is not reachable anymore.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tls.mbed.org` only had the latest version, and then it froze at some point and was showing an old version until it went down. I haven't found a site hosting multiple versions of the documentation.

You can typeset the documentation on a typical Unix-like system (e.g. Linux or macOS or WSL or Cygwin) by checking out the version you want from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls). This has the advantage that you can typeset the documentation for your configuration: after setting `mbedtls/mbedtls_config.h` (`mbedtls/config.h` in Mbed TLS 2.x), run

```
make apidoc
```

and browse `apidoc/modules.html` or `apidoc/files.html`.

If you want the whole documentation including all compile-time options and features that may or may not be enabled in your build, run

```
scripts/apidoc_full.sh
```

Note that this overwrites `mbedtls/mbedtls_config.h`.